# On refresh don't redirect to login page

Tags: javascript, php

I have an web application that has one page i.e. index.php. 
It has two three div's with classes
1-login
2-home and 
3-about respectively
when the user first browse the url, div with class login is shown.

After login with username and password a session is set and div with class login is hide and div with class home is shown.

*What I want*: When user refreshes, div with class home should shown. div with class login should be hide yet.and if the session is expired and user refreshes, the login div should be shown and rest divs should be hide. php and javascript is used for coding.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've done already?

Comment: if (cache.session) {showMain} else {showLogin}

Comment: You storyboarded your question, now do the same for the code you'll need to write for it. FYI: "storyboarding" is a term used in animation to outline action steps to be taken from point A to point B.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, I woud recommend adding something like

```
    if($_SESSION['Online'] != null){ header('Location: mainpage.php'); }
```

to your login site, wich redirects you to your mainpage if you are online and try to enter the login site;